# titanium exit from app global function

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-widgets

i have a application which uses drawer widget..so in that drawer js file i have a button which users can click and exit..but it is not working.

Here is my **index.js** file

```
var win = $.index;
```

here is my **drawer.js** file

```
var button = $.exit;

button .addEventListener('android:back',function(e) {
  win.close();
});
```

**When the user click the button the app should exit..Thank you!**

Comment: Working on iOS or android

Answer (score 0):

`'android:back'` event is deprecated, you should use `'androidback'` instead.
So the proper drawer.js should look like this:

```
var button = $.exit;

button .addEventListener('androidback',function(e) { 
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.finish(); //this is a proper way to close the application in android
});
```